# What do I need to buy to run an airbrush on this compressor?

Tags: tool-selection, tool-modification, airbrush

I've used airbrushes before, but only in art classes, so I know very little about them beyond using them to paint with.

This is the compressor that I already own. I'd rather not buy another as I don't want to have to store two of them.

What do I need to buy in order to fit a generic mid range airbrush to it. If possible, could you please link to Amazon or an art supply store as I don't yet know what all of the terminology means.

I'm going to be painting models, mostly getting smooth base coats down at first, then moving on to details once I'm more experienced.

I'm going to need something to reduce the pressure and to allow me to control it close by so that I don't have to keep going to the compressor to do it (It's probably going to be outside), as well as dust\oil\water traps.

[image: Compressor]

[image: Connections]

[image: Gauges]

[image: Accessories]

[image: Boiler Plate]

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much answered your own question. The obvious parts are sufficient length of hose, a water/oil trap at the compressor and one close to you and the correct fittings to convert from the quick-release fitting on the end of the hose to the airbrush fitting.

Most compressors use NPT/BSP threaded connections, so you'd need something based on that thread. Amazon has a [female BSP to airbrush adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004KNBW6E):

[image: airbrush adapter]

Image from linked site.

Note that BSP is British threading, while NPT is USA tapered threading. You'd have to check your airbrush for the type of connection and match it to the fitting on the last air/oil trap (with regulator for pressure adjustment.)

When I searched for NPT to airbrush adapter, tons of conflicting results appeared, with far more adapters than I expected. My compressor required that I purchase an adapter kit, from which only one fit the airbrush!

Comment: I understand enough to know that I need traps, but not enough to buy one that's suitable. I'm looking for recommendations of products if possible.

Comment: recommendations on SE are tough and some of them reject such requests. Budget of the purchaser plays a big part, which could turn a Q/A post into a discussion, also disallowed. If you find a water/oil separator which meets your budget and has the correct connections and has a maintenance schedule you accept, you've found your device. Pressure regulators fit the same concept, although for airbrushing, an economy version is probably going to be okay.

Comment: We do not do product recommend on SE because the data is opinion based, will likely go out of date soon, and invites spam.